# how to pass strings between activities parsed with JSON on android application?

Tags: java, android, json, string, parsing

I am attempting to pass a string between 2 separate activities parsed with JSON from a DB in an android application. The code compiles in MainActivity but I have errors in SingleContactActivity. Specifically, the error is on the string test extras..... line in SingleContactActicity. 
Using this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Also, I removed imports to reduce the code clutter, if needed I can re-add them

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
public static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

// JSON Node names

private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";


// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                    .getText().toString();

            // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleContactActivity.class);

            //getApplicationContext()

            // sending data to new activity
            in.putExtra("TAG_NAME", name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
```

I am only passing name at this point to test if it works.

```
public class SingleContactActivity extends Activity {


@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  
    String test extras.getString("TAG_NAME");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fix this error:

```
String test =  extras.getString("TAG_NAME");
```

instead of

```
String test extras.getString("TAG_NAME");
```

Other than that everything seems fine.

Try this:
In MainActivity

```
     // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
        Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleContactActivity.class);

           // sending data to new activity
        in.putExtra("TAG_NAME", "Name is passed here!");
        in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
        in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
        startActivity(in);
```

In SingleContactActivity

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if( extras != null ) {
          String test = extras.getString("TAG_NAME");
          Log.d("", "Value passed = " + test);
     }

    }
```

Comment: No errors, but it doesn't pass the string when I run the app

Comment: @user3192423, try my edit and tell me what you got. You should see "Value passed = Name is passed here!" in your logcat.

Comment: I did what you said, nothing showed up in the new activity on the AVD. But I checked log cat and all it said was "Value passed = null"

Comment: Your problem is your using in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name); when sending, and using String test = extras.getString("TAG_NAME"); when receiving. Change to  in.putExtra("TAG_NAME", name) when sending and check. The double quotation are very important, either you use them on both or dont use them at all.

Comment: In SingleContactActivity i changed 
String test = extras.getString("TAG_NAME");
In MainActivity
changed in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name); ---->>>>
in.putExtra("TAG_NAME", name);
Ran the app, no errors, selected activity- still does not return activity

Comment: Since I am utilizing an http request from using JSON format, should I just request the strings again in the new activity instead of attempting to pass it between activities?

Comment: Yes! Thats how I would do it.

Comment: Since "Name is passed here!" is in my logcat what should I do next codewise? How can I make it pass the string "Name is passed here!" and out put it in the new activity?

Comment: Scratch that, I added to the if(extras != ....{

TextView txtContact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
         txtContact.setText(test); 
}
and it works! thanks for the help